# Add role to AspNetUserRoles

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Well im kind wasting too much time trying to accomplish this objective and im kinda frustrated, what i want to do is something like that:

**table aspNetUserRoles
userId
roleId

table aspNetRole
roleId
RoleName**

i already did the first part i already filled the aspNetUserRoles with the seed method and have some roles in my database, and i already created a dropdownlist with all my roles, but i have a problem when i press Register i get a error : "UserId not found" i will show here what i alrady did and will place my 2 tables

**what i did**

```
 [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, Sobre = model.Sobre, Idade = model.Idade, Telemóvel = model.Telemóvel, Nome = model.Nome };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            var roleStore = new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(db);
            var roleManager = new RoleManager<IdentityRole>(roleStore);

            var userStore = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(db);
            var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(userStore);
            userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Name");

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

if someone can me explain what i am doing wrong i appreciate a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

use Like this

```
if (result.Succeeded)
{
userManager.AddToRole(user.Id, "Name");
}
```